# Clone GIT Repository Subfolder into existing Repo with identical folder structure

Tags: git, github

Repository A)

> MAIN `../repository_A/`
>
> `../repository_A/some_directory/some_files`

Repository B)

> MAIN `../repository_B/`
>
> `../repository_B/SRC/some_directory/some_files`

**The repository_B structure is identical to the repository_A structure,
 except for the /SRC/ directory which is in place because the main directory of repository_B has a `.gitmodules` file.**

The ultimate goal is to clone/merge the content of `/repository_B/SRC/` directory into `/repository_A/` root - the folder structure is identical, so we need to write into existing folders of repository_A - for example write content of `repository_B/SRC/includes` directory into `repository_A/includes`.

Behind the task is that i have a modular system which is repository_A that is extended through modules which are represented by repository_B.

Another option that would do the job too would be to `mv` `repository_A` into another directory so that the folder structure is identical to `repository_B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need to git clone, but you will need a git merge.

1. I would match repository A's folder structure to repository B, i.e. create /SRC/ folder to match repository B.
2. git commit/push repository's A's new structure.
3. If you want to merge repository B into repository A:

   ```
   cd path/to/repo-A
   git remote add repo-a path/to/repo-B
   git fetch repo-B
   git merge repo-B/master # or whichever branch you want to merge
   git remote remove repo-B
   ```

Reference: [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories/10548919#10548919)

Comment: Great - is there anything todo to track repo_B?

Comment: If you want, create a tag of where you merged in repo_B like so: `git tag v1.0` then push your tags `git push origin --tags`.